# Boost-Python C++ project builds, How to use the new library from Python?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2012, pycharm, boost-python

I have a VS12 project and exposed some of the classes to Python using boost-python. After some linkage issues my project finally builds correctly and generates a `MySDK.lib` and `MySDK.dll`. I called the Boost Python module the same as the library i.e. `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MySDK)`. Are these `.lib` and `.dll` all I need to use `MySDK` from Python?

I'm using Pycharm Community but can't find a way to import the generated `MySDK.lib` and `MySDK.dll` as a Python library module.

Saddly there isn't much information of what to do after the Boost Python coding exercise.

Comment: This question suggests a similar probelm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842074/pycharm-does-not-find-extension-libraries Can you make yours work outside PyCharm?

Comment: Actualy it is worse than that. After adding the lib and dll locations to my Path variable. I go to the command line run the python interpreter and this is what I get: `ImportError: No module named MySDK`

Comment: Inside PyCharm or not?

Comment: @doctorlove all good now thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my VS12 project output file extension to `.pyd` (`Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Output File -> changed to $(OutDir)$(TargetName).pyd`) and now I can load the library in Python from the command line but still can't from Pycharm.

After that, made the directory where the `.pyd` (along with `.lib` and `.dll`) is located under the `Path` variable. Then Pycharm is able to successfully load and run my custom boost-python library.

**UPDATE** The pyd that Python understands and can load is simply the `dll` renamed to `pyd`. Therefore, an even cleaner way is to leave the VS12 project as is generating the original `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)` i.e. `dll` output and simply add a `Post-Build Event` that copies the `dll` into a `pyd`:

(`Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Build Events -> Post-Build Event -> Command Line`) and add `copy $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt) $(OutDir)$(TargetName).pyd`